# Javascript Regular Exp

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to understand how Regex handles searching for literals of special characters. This is the simplest example I can think of to illustrate my question.


I am searching for a literal . in a string

When I do

```
 'sp.o'.search('.')
 //it returns 0 which makes sense.
```

Then I read the MDN and according to them

```
 'sp.o'.search('\.')
 // it returns 0 !
 // I come from vim flavor regex
 // It does not make sense to me =(
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

```
 'sp.o'.search('\\.')
 // returns 2 !
 // the correct out put I am looking for
```

What the heck am I missing !
( This behavior is both in Google Chrome and NodeJS I have not tried any where else! )

Comment: Why use regex to search for simple literals? `.indexOf()` is much less expensive.

Comment: I am asking about REGEX. I think my title confused people. I just gave the simplest example of the issue.

Comment: Every ones complaint is fair enough. I cleared up my question sry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because its a string, the `\` means you want to escape the next character. but `.` isn't a special string character so it just treats it as a literal.

```
"\." === "."
```

You want to escape the slash (`\`) not the period, which is why `"\\."` produces the literal string `\.` which is what you want. Or more explicity:

`"\\" + "." === "\\." // or a literal: \.`

But the other posts are correct, you probably just want to use a Regex literal, rather than parsing a string as a regex.

Answer (score 4):

You are not using regular expressions but strings. Use:

```
/regexphere/
```

It works:

```
'sp.o'.search(/\./); // 2
```

But in your case, `.indexOf` is your friend:

```
'sp.o'.indexOf('.'); // 2
```

Comment: Strings can be used, they are just converted to a RegExp.

Comment: @benekastah: I just noticed that. Wouldn't advise to use it, though.

Comment: is that safe across a majority of platforms?

Comment: @pimvdb True. Your `.indexOf` suggestion is better. +1

Comment: @James Andino: For strings, `indexOf` is widely supported as far as I know. This is not the case for array's `indexOf`, though.

Comment: I was referring to 'sp.o'.search(/\./);  just droppinig the regex into the function. indexOf is a great suggestion. I gave it to the other one because it really answered my question of why the regex was not working like I expected. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Your usage is almost correct. As others noted, you can use regular expression literals instead of strings. But strings also work. According to the [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) on the search method:

> If a non-RegExp object obj is passed, it is implicitly converted to a RegExp by using new RegExp(obj).

The reason `'\\.'` works and `'\.'` does not is because in a javascript string you must escape the backslash for it to be a backslash. Otherwise it will always try to escape the character in front of it. In this case, `'.'` doesn't escape to anything. If you evaluate your strings in a javascript console, you will get this:

```
'\.' // => '.'
'\\.' // => '\.'
```

The string will then be passed to the `RegExp` object behind the scenes. If you do this yourself, this is what you'd get:

```
new RegExp('\.') // => /./
new RegExp('\\.') // => /\./
```

Other people suggested using the regex literal (e.g. `/\./`) instead of a string as the argument to `.search`. Both work, but I would use the regex literal because it is more obvious and a little prettier.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just searching for a fixed literal, why not just use:

```
if( 'sp.o'.indexOf('.') !== -1) ...
```

Regex is always more expensive than a string search.

Answer (score 1):

You are searching with a string, not an expression. Try this:

```
'sp.o'.search(/\./); // should return 2
```